# opening a new frame from object on gui(ball)

Tags: if-statement, jframe, system.exit

Im creating a game which is basically a target practise game which will have multiple balls on the screen and you click on them and they will disappear.

My problem is that I want the program to end the game if the green ball is hit. When I use system.exit(abort) it closes the whole program but I just want it to end the game and call the ending frame.

any help would be appreciated.

Code below :

```
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mousePressed(e);

            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                if ((new Ellipse2D.Double(ball.positionX, ball.positionY, ball.size, ball.size))
                .contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    clicksLandedOnABall++;
                    if (ball.ballColour == Color.GREEN)
                    {

                }
                    ball.ballColour = Color.WHITE;
                }
            }               
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is going to require much more context.